Unable to save X509Certificate2 with its private key in X509Store
I am trying to stay away from CERTENROLLLib, I've been trying to use the vanilla .NET8 CertificateRequest to generate a CSR, get a certificate back and the re-integrate the private key back into the certificate before storing it back in the Windows' X509Store within  StoreName.My.
The code I have here, when I debug them, it shows that the private key is back into the cert, but after storing it, I am not able to export the certificate with its private key... is basically not there. Is there a way I could archive that I described here?
public static readonly X509KeyStorageFlags InstallFlags = X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
                                                          X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
                                                          X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet;

byte[] rawData = Convert.FromBase64String(x509Base64);
using (var tmp = new X509Certificate2(rawData, "", InstallFlags))
{
    string pubKey = Convert.ToBase64String(tmp.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData);

    SomeTempCryptoDictionary.TryGetValue(pubKey, out var crypto);
    using (var certWithPrivateKey = tmp.CopyWithPrivateKey((RSA) crypto))
    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(certWithPrivateKey);
        store.Close();

        certWithPrivateKey.Reset();
    }
}

I am not sure if I am allowed to put empty password there, but it did not complaint and it did not throw any error, I definitely cannot pass null. This feels like, I am REALLY close to getting it to work without CERTENROLLLib just not sure what else I am missing...?
This is the part where CSR was generated using CertificateRequest.
RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
X500DistinguishedName dn = new X500DistinguishedName("CN=HelloWorld");
CertificateRequest csr = new CertificateRequest(dn, rsa,
                                                HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                                                RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
string pubKey = Convert.ToBase64String(csr.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData);
// saved to be use when it comes back
SomeTempCryptoDictionary.Add(pubKey, rsa);

return Convert.ToBase64String(csr.CreateSigningRequest());

Edit: Per @bartonjs suggestion, still the same result even when trying to export/import as Pkcs12
using (var certWithPrivateKey = tmp.CopyWithPrivateKey((RSA) crypto))
using (var certExportable = new X509Certificate2(certWithPrivateKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12)))
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))


You can't export a non-exportable key. And that depends on the flags used when creating that private key, it cannot be changed afterwards.

@Charlieface I did marked it as exportable via X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable flag though. When I do new X509Certificate2 with the raw bytes + the install flags, it "should" be exportable, I've used those same flags before but it was to install a p12 with password protected. I do not see any flags that I could use when generating the private key via RSA.Create(), could you kindly point me to the right direction?

Wait why are you adding certExportable that doesn't have the private key in it? You should be adding certWithPrivateKey to the store, and put InstallFlags in tmp constructor. The certExportable seems completely unnecessary and counterproductive.

@Charlieface updated the code with what you've pointed out, but the result is still the same.

Oh wow... what madness is this? So, if I take my certWithPrivateKey export it into an actual password protected p12 file, then manually import it into the Windows store, then the private key would be there and it would be exportable!!!!! WTF!

In your line:
using (var certExportable = new X509Certificate2(certWithPrivateKey.GetRawCertData(), "", InstallFlags))

You should use certWithPrivateKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12) instead of .GetRawCertData().  The method you called exports the certificate without the private key; you need it to be a PKCS#12/PFX to have both the certificate and the private key.
You should be able to see this easily in that certExportable.HasPrivateKey should currently be false, but once you change the export format it will be true.
That does require, of course, that the private key object (crypto) is already representing an exportable key.

I tried this just now, still the same. When you say the crypto (RSA object) already representing an exportable key, how do I assert that? Is the code I have when generating the CSR not enough? The keypair should be inside that RSA object no? When I debug the certificate, HasPrivateKey is set, but when it gets to the store, it never shows the option to let me export the private key.

If you are using NET 9 then I would give this a try:
public X509Certificate2 Generate(SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder sanBuilder, DateTimeOffset expire, string certificateName)
{
    var distinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN={certificateName}");
    using var rsa = RSA.Create(4096);
    var request = new CertificateRequest(distinguishedName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA384, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(_usageFlags, true));
    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(_keyPurposes, true));
    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

    using var certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), expire);


    if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
    {
        certificate.FriendlyName = certificateName;
    }
    var exportableCert = X509CertificateLoader.LoadPkcs12(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12), null, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    return StoreCertificate(exportableCert);
}

As to your error, are you missing the X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable flags?
